# How to get list of Folders and subfolders created in "List"?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to access list of all Sites and Lists from Sharepoint 2007 using c#.
I am able to get Name of sites and list.
But unable to get folders and subfolders of particular list.
And Document uploaded in particular Folder.

I am using Web Services (no dependency of Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll)

Regards,

Jene

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPList list = web.Lists["your_doclib"];
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery()
    {
        Query = "",
        ViewAttributes = @"Scope=""RecursiveAll"""
    };
    SPListItemCollection itens = list.GetItems(query);
    foreach (SPListItem item in itens)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor =
            item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder ?
                ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx Rubens but i am not using Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll (sorry i din't mentioned it before in post).

I am using Web services in my code.Can you give solution on that?

Comment: Take a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/paulballard/archive/2005/05/08/Using-Data-From-SharePoint-2003-Lists.aspx